# How to get the active farm-scoped features in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

If i want to get the Features that are activated on a WebApplication, i can use the [SPWebApplication.Features property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spwebapplication.features%28v=office.15%29.aspx), which will return a SPFeatureCollection with the Features activated for the WebApplication.

If i want to get a collection with the Farm-scoped Features that are activated on a SharePoint-Farm, there is not an easy way (as in the above for WebApps) to achieve this, since there is no 'SPFarm.Features' [or similar] property.

So how do i get a collection of farm-scoped features that are activated ?

Answer (score 4):

To get the SPFeatureCollection for the farm-scoped features in the same fashion as SPWebApplication.Features, you use the SPWebService.AdministrationService.  In PowerShell:

```
[Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::AdministrationService.Features
```

In C#:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService.AdministrationService.Features
```

Answer (score 2):

To get all features grouped by Scope (Farm, WebApplication, Site, Web):

`Get-SPFeature | Sort -Property Scope, DisplayName | FT -GroupBy Scope DisplayName, Id`

To get Farm features only:

`Get-SPFeature | Where {$_.Scope -eq "Farm"} | Select DisplayName, Id | Sort -Property Scope, DisplayName`

Answer (score 2):

Use below Powershell to get all activated features in the farm

```
$farmFeatures = Get-SPFeature -Farm
```